# При редактировании ответа оказались учтены не только мои изменения

Tags: дефект

При редактировании [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/221232) были убраны лишние слова из описания к ответу, но при этом в мои изменения попали изменения кода. Видимо автор ответа в момент моего редактирования ответа успел отредактировать ответ и в мои изменения попал старый код. В итоге получается, что моя правка убирает лишние слова, но делает пример кода некорректным. Как поступать в такой ситуации? Нельзя ведь отменить свои изменения, находящиеся на проверке?

Comment: Можно ещё раз отредактировать вопрос, тогда предлагаемая правка будет изменена (если предлагаемая правка ещё не принята/отклонена, то изменения отразятся на старой предлагаемой правке, новая создана не будет)